# SQL query to get average values over a list of time ranges

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like to get the average value of some columns for a list of time ranges. The time ranges are not fixed so it is not the average value for every year or month.

I don't want to do a query against the database for every range and I would like, if possible, to do this query only once.

So it would be cool if we could replace the following queries for 2 time ranges to only one query.

```
SELECT AVG(column1) FROM Table1 WHERE dateColumn > startRange1 && dateColumn < endRange1
SELECT AVG(column1) FROM Table1 WHERE dateColumn > startRange2 && dateColumn < endRange2
```

**NOTE:** The list of time ranges can varies between 1 to 12 specified ranges.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`case based aggregation` is one way to do this in single query.

```
SELECT AVG(case when dateColumn > startRange1 && dateColumn < endRange1 then column1 end) as range1Avg,
       AVG(case when dateColumn > startRange2 && dateColumn < endRange2 then column1 end) as range2Avg
FROM Table1
```